# When I run this code I get a "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" error from the pytesseract library

Tags: python, python-tesseract

The purpose of the program is to take a picture of handwritten inquiry card and submit the information written on to an online form.

Code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

# Open the image file using PIL library
image = Image.open('inquirycard.jpg')

# Extract text from the image using pytesseract
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)

# Save the extracted text to a file
with open('extracted_text.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(text)

import pandas as pd

# Read the extracted text file using Pandas
df = pd.read_csv('extracted_text.txt', delimiter='\t', header=None)

# Save the text to a CSV file
df.to_csv('extracted_text.csv', index=False)

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Open the online form using Selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://your-online-form-url.com')

# Find the input element on the online form using its ID
input_element = driver.find_element_by_id('input-element-id')

# Read the text from the spreadsheet using Pandas
df = pd.read_csv('extracted_text.csv')
text = df.to_string(index=False, header=False)

# Enter the text into the input element and submit the form
input_element.send_keys(text)
input_element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

This is the error I receive "Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Users\*******\********\*******\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 255, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\*******\******\untitled\Main.py", line 8, in <module>
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
  File "C:\Users\******\********\*******\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 423, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "C:\Users\******\********\*******\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 426, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\Users\*********\******\*******\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 288, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*******\*******\*********\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 260, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information."
```

I couldn't figure out what the problem was.

Comment: `pytesseract` is a module that provides a Python wrapper for Tesseract, but it does not install Tesseract.  Have you read the installation instructions?

Comment: I installed the Tesseract package but nothing changed

Comment: Did you tell pytesseract where to find Tesseract?  On Windows, it can't find it automatically.